# How to put two container over same stack with both having same height

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement the following design in the flutter.
[image]

This is one item of the `ListView`children.
Also the text mentioned in the image is dynamic and therefore i don't want to give static heigh of the main `Container` that means the area in the left side that is the green one should automatically fit the second `Container` containing the text.

What i am trying to do right now is :

```
    Container(
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                    width: 15,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(5))),
                                
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                  left: 10,
                                  top: 1,
                                  bottom: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: Spacing.padding12,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Text(
                                        'Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content'),
                                  ))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [boxShadow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/boxShadow.html) instead. Something like this:

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(5),
    ),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.green,
        offset: Offset(-5.0, 0.0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: const Text('...'),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code[image] works like what you want:

```
Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: Colors.green),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    height: 150,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    width: 300,
                    child: Text("Lorem text"),
                  ),
                ),
```